# Want to pass enviormnet values from text file in perl

Tags: perl

I'm having this below code in which we are passing value of ENVIRONMENT and `ENV` NUMBER manually in script. I want to maintain one script and to pass all the values of ENVIRONMENT name and their values from some text file. So that I don't need to update it in future.

Can anyone help me the way how I can do this ?

I have cut down my code and kept only part where i'm facing issue. I want all these input(UAT/PET/QA/SIT and their env number) from some text file. I don't want it to be hard coded in script.

```
if ( $environment ne "" || $environment ne "Select" ) {
   print "<td> <select name=environment onchange=document.form1.submit()>";
   print "<option selected value=$environment>$environment</option> ";

   print "<option value=UAT>UAT</option> ";
   print "<option value=PET>PET</option> ";
   print "<option value=QA>QA</option> ";
   print "<option value=SIT>SIT</option> ";
}
print "</tr>";


if ( $environment eq "" || $environment eq "Select" ) {
   print "<td> <INPUT TYPE=text disabled NAME=product size=21 > </td>";
}
else {
   if ( $environment eq "MPET" ) {
      print "<td> <select name=product onchange=document.form1.submit()>";
      print "<option selected value=$product>$product</option> ";
      print "<option value=1>1</option> ";
      print "<option value=2>2</option> ";
      print "<option value=3>3</option> ";
      print "<option value=4>4</option> ";
   }
   if ( $environment eq "QA" ) {
      print "<td> <select name=product onchange=document.form1.submit()>";
      print "<option selected value=$product>$product</option> ";
      print "<option value=1>1</option> ";
      print "<option value=2>2</option> ";
   }

   if ( $environment eq "UAT" ) {
      print "<td> <select name=product onchange=document.form1.submit()>";
      print "<option selected value=$product>$product</option> ";
      print "<option value=1>1</option> ";
      print "<option value=3>3</option> ";
      print "<option value=4>4</option> ";
   }
   if ( $environment eq "SIT" ) {
      print "<td> <select name=product onchange=document.form1.submit()>";
      print "<option selected value=$product>$product</option> ";
      print "<option value=1>1</option> ";
   }
   print "<input type=hidden name=environment value='$environment'>";
   print "</td> ";
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please format your code?

Comment: What is this huge lump of code? Please post only what is relevant. Please read [mcve] and then rewrite your question.

Comment: I have reformatted your code - I've taken the liberty of removing the `**` in there, because that _looks_ like you've accidentally included formatting characters from SE markup, rather than actual code. (And removing them means your code compiles, where without there's syntax errors ). However I'd urge you to cut back your code somewhat, and focus on the basic issue.

Comment: Could you please check now.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to keep them in a file, I'd recommend going with an INI-style configuration file, then use [Config::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Config::Tiny) to read out the data when needed. You could write your own custom format and retrieval functionality, but `Config::Tiny` is very easy to use, and makes it easy to write to the config file if you ever need to. Also, INI files are standardized, so there's that as well.

Here's the INI file example:

```
[variables]
ORACLE_HOME=/ora/11.2.0.3
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/ora/11.2.0.3/lib
```

...and the code:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

use Config::Tiny;

my $file = 'env.ini';

my $conf = Config::Tiny->read($file);

$ENV{ORACLE_HOME} = $conf->{variables}{ORACLE_HOME};
my $LD_LIBRARY_PATH = $conf->{variables}{LD_LIBRARY_PATH};

print "ora home: $ENV{ORACLE_HOME}\n";
print "lib path: $LD_LIBRARY_PATH\n";
```

...and the output:

```
ora home: /ora/11.2.0.3
lib path: /ora/11.2.0.3/lib
```

You'll likely want to do some sanity checking while you're setting the variables, so that if there's one that's missing or not correct, you can exit your application before reaching parts of code that will break unexpectedly.